# CVS Repository Migration to new CVS Server

Tags: linux, version-control, solaris, cvs

i have a CVS Repository in Solaris machine, now i want to move this repository to anathor CVS server in anathor machine, can anyone please tell me the steps to migrate the CVS repository to the new CVS server. existing server is running in extssh protocol and i want to move it to Pserver protocol.

Answer (score 0):

CVS is a very simple environment.  To move the repository over, just copy the files that are in the repository.  If you like, tar it up, copy the tar to the new machine, and untar it.  Most of the per-directory configuration will be stored along with the rest of the files in the tarball.

The parts of the configuration that are *not* included within the repository will need to be set up according to the instructions for setting up CVS on your target platform, whatever that is.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply Graham, can u please explain more on this, should i have to move CVSROOT folder also, without modifying

Comment: You have to move the whole CVS reposiotry try without exception. CVSROOT folder contains modules etc. which is important.

Comment: Can u please confirm the steps                                          1. copy entire repository to the new system(Including CVSROOT without modifying) eg: from ABC(repository) folder from old system to ABC folder in new system                                                             2. point the CVSROOT to the newly copied Repository eg: ABC.                                         After this should i have to restart any services? or i can just access by pointing to new repository Path. I have to do this in solaris Machine(existing machine is also solaris)